# Retrieve the values if the adjacent cell contains a given string

Tags: google-sheets

This is how my spreadsheet looks like:

2 spreadsheets: `Foo` and `Bar`.
`Foo` only has one cell, `A1`.
`Bar` has `n` rows and `2` columns.

Now I want to have a formula in `A1` so that it sums up all values in the 2nd column of `Bar`s spreadsheet, if the adjacent column contains a given string.

So for example if my `Bar` spreadsheet looks like this:

```
-----------------
Machine A  | 500 |
Mach    B  | 321 |
Door       |  34 |
Machines C |   2 |
-----------------
```

`A1` should now sum up all values of the rows where the first column's cell contains either the word `Machine`, `Mach` or `Machines`, thus the value in `A1` would be 823.

I suppose it is some combination of `IF`, `SEARCH`/`FIND`, but my main problem is to address the adjacent value cell, if the a string is found.

Comment: @pnuts It should work for Google Sheets. I was just assuming that if it works in Excel that it will work in Google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
=sumif(Bar!A:A,"=*Mach*",Bar!B:B)
```

Comment: Awesome! Instead of the commas, it has to be a semicolon though: `=sumif(Bar!A:A;"=*Mach*";Bar!B:B)`

Comment: +1 Really? Semicolon(;) ? Anyway, good that it worked out. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583